# Twitter bootstrap 3.0.2 change when navbar dropdown goes to stack instead of overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a navbar in twbs 3.0.2 which has collapses at `@screen-md` I want to change to look of dropdown menu's. I want them to open as indented menu instead of an overlay (see picture)

Where is this located in the configuration or how do i add my custom CSS to override this behavior?

Current dropdown layout
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vHlJ.png

I want to have this stacked version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hwTO.png

EDIT: After some testing i found that at 768px the change from an overlay dropdown to stacked dropdown occurs but I can't seem to find this anywhere in the css files

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to target the collapsed version of the dropdown menus. Increase the left padding to make them indent...

```
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
```

## [**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/93455)

Comment: does not seem to work it adds padding but does not change the the overlay dropdown to the one I looking for on iPad sized screens

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. You want it to overlay the page content or push it down on small screens?

Comment: I want it to always display as a stacked version(second picture) when the navbar is collapsed. If the navbar is not collapsed it has to look as first picture. at this moment the change occurs at around 768px not at screen-md (998px)